# Make git track data that is scattered across the disk

Tags: git, msysgit

My project is set up so that I have source code and configuration files separate folders.

For clarity, here is the basic folder structure:

```
C:\SourceCode
C:\ConfigFiles1
C:\ConfigFiles2
C:\ConfigFiles3
```

This causes a problem because I want to track all of these folders using Git. Git, on the other hand, seems to want every tracked file to be contained within a single top-level folder.

If, for example, the .git folder is located in SourceCode (**git init /c/SourceCode**), it will refuse to add ConfigFiles1 (**git add ../ConfigFiles1**) because it is outside of the repository.

I would like to avoid creating a repository directly on C:\ (**git init /c**) if possible, because that just seems messy. Nevertheless, I'll take what I can get.

I am unable to move these configuration files to a more convenient location. I'm stuck with this folder structure.

FYI, in my case, I'm using Git on Windows (msysgit)

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to put config files into SourceCode directory? If so, you may want to track Config files as git submodules in SourceCode dir.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to move anything around, the best solution I can think of is a detached worktree. Create a bare Git repository in C:\ProjectTracker (or just about anywhere else) and set `core.worktree` = C:\; just remember to keep a large `.gitignore` file to ignore all the other files in C:\